# Generating a script that disables foreign keys in many tables

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

I'm working on a refresh script where we

1. `DROP` the table constraints,
2. `TRUNCATE` the table,
3. `INSERT` data in the table and
4. `ADD` the constraints that are dropped at the first step.

I created the following SQL using dynamic SQL to genarate a SQL DROP foreign key constraint so that I can execute for multiple tables I'm working on,

```
SELECT 
'ALTER TABLE  SSP2_PCAT.' || TABLE_NAME || ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' || CONSTRAINT_NAME || ';' 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE 
UPPER(CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA) = 'SSP2_PCAT' AND
UPPER(TABLE_NAME) IN (RATES,.....);
```

The output of above SQL is going to be as follows,

`ALTER TABLE SSP2_PCAT.RATES DROP CONSTRAINT fk_rate;`

Mentioned above truncate is done as its very straight forward.

Used the `WITH` clause with `STRING_AGG` function by enabling the DBlink 
Extensions in the POSTGRES similarly using Dynamic SQL so that it gives SQL for multiple tables at one shot.

Now I'm working on a similar query to ADD the constraints as follows, (that are dropped in the first step),

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'ALTER TABLE  ' || cs.TABLE_NAME || 
' ADD CONSTRAINT ' ||rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME ||
' FOREIGN KEY ' ||c.COLUMN_NAME ||
' REFERENCES ' ||cs.TABLE_NAME || ' (' || cs.CONSTRAINT_NAME || ') ' || ' ON UPDATE ' || rc.UPDATE_RULE || ' ON DELETE ' || rc.DELETE_RULE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS RC, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS CS, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
WHERE cs.CONSTRAINT_NAME = rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME AND
cs.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME AND
UPPER(cs.TABLE_NAME) = 'ADDITIONAL_RULES' AND
UPPER(cs.TABLE_SCHEMA) = 'SSP2_PCAT';
```

But unfortunately this query is not giving the desired result, looks like I'm missing something as its especially when selecting the `c.COLUMN_NAME`field instead of the references field it's giving all the available fields in the table, also it's not giving the name of the Parent_table `cs.TABLE_NAME` rather it's giving the same table_name. Can someone please keep me posted if I'm missing any join from any other data dictionary tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to drop and recreate foreign keys. Use deferred constraints instead. It's enough when you define foreign keys as `deferrable initially deferred` and execute all inserts in a single transaction. There are more options, however, so read about deferrable constraints in the documentation:

- [CREATE TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html)
- [SET CONSTRAINTS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-constraints.html)

---

Use the system catalog [`pg_constraint`.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-constraint.html)

You can generate a script to alter foreign keys to `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED` in this way:

```
select format(
    'ALTER TABLE %s ALTER CONSTRAINT %s DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;', 
    conrelid::regclass::text, 
    conname)
from pg_constraint
where contype = 'f' 
and conrelid = any(array['table1', 'table2', 'table3']::regclass[])
and connamespace = 'ssp2_pcat'::regnamespace;
```

You can run the script once. Then your import script may look like this:

```
BEGIN;
TRUNCATE table1;
TRUNCATE table2;
...
INSERT INTO table1...
INSERT INTO table2...
...
COMMIT;
```

---

If for some reason you cannot use deferred constraints, use the script to drop constraints:

```
select
    format(
        'ALTER TABLE %s DROP CONSTRAINT %s;', 
        conrelid::regclass::text, 
        conname)
from pg_constraint
where contype = 'f' 
and conrelid = any(array['table1', 'table2', 'table3']::regclass[])
and connamespace = 'ssp2_pcat'::regnamespace;
```

and to recreate them:

```
select
    format(
        'ALTER TABLE %s ADD CONSTRAINT %s %s;', 
        conrelid::regclass::text, 
        conname, 
        pg_get_constraintdef(oid))
from pg_constraint
where contype = 'f' 
and conrelid = any(array['table1', 'table2', 'table3']::regclass[])
and connamespace = 'ssp2_pcat'::regnamespace;
```

Comment: Hi Klin, Can you please help me out with syntax for better understanding ? As all these are existing tables in Postgres, even I will look at it too, once at work ., Thanks for your time ✅

Comment: Klin, thank you for the answer, 
But the actual question is we have around 150 tables in Oracle that are moved to Postgres with same data n structure, now we have a Refresh Scripts to be run on daily basis, 
The refresh script in Oracle includes
i) Disable Const (125), Trunc table (150), insert data (150) and enable Constr (125)
These numbers in brackets are DML and DDL statements

Now I want to convert them into Postgres,
Since I can't disable the Constr here, I used Dynamical SQL to save time and generate the SQL statements,
But unfortunately its not Working for ADD Constr Query,

Comment: I don't get it. You know how to *drop* the constraints but cannot *alter* them?

Comment: Yes, I'm still working on it, Its simply, writing a SQL Query dynamically using data dictionary tables that generates an Output which is an ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT...,,,,
which I can run separately tweaking the filter condition to run it for around 150 tables, at some shot if possible.
Hope this is clear!

Comment: The SQL OUTPUT for the first row is as follows,

`ALTER TABLE  additional_rules ADD CONSTRAINT fk1_addnl_rules FOREIGN KEY  (promotion_id,offer_id)  REFERENCES additional_rules (offer_id,promotion_id,channel,rule_grp_cd,rule_subgp_cd,rule_type,rule_start_date,rule_value,addnl_ruleid,promotion_id,offer_id)  ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION`                

But its not giving the Parent table after the REFERENCES clause in the above statement and its also giving the PRIMARY KEY fields, rather than fields from the referenced Parent Table corresponding to the Foreign Key!!!

Comment: klin - You are incredidible, Postgres Guru!  By the way it worked perfect to fit my requirement.,
Thanks a ton for looking into this from your busy schedule,

Comment: Great thing. We can improve it by combining last two SQL statements into one.